# How to fetch the menu at custom template dynamically in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i want to fetch the menu with items dynamically..
`This is my code what i have tried :`

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location' => 'primary','menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav' ,'menu' => 'tahrid'));?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You want to _get_ the menu items, but not output them? Why do you keep saying "dynamically"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add this code to your *functions.php* file.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'header-top' => __( 'Header Top', 'twentyseventeen' )
) );
```

and then on your *index.php* add this which had worked for me.

```
?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'header-top' ) ) : ?>
                                <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'header-top',
                                    'menu_id'        => 'header-top',
                                ) ); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```